# Making a primary key not "auto-increment" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables, primary-key

Is it possible to make a primary key (that is gonna be used as a foreign key) not having auto-increment. Imagine a actor typing in his/her id from a different source. I want to take this random int value and store it as primary

Comment: it has to be unique, so the possibilitys are limited, you can also use your own programming to create a unique key, but why bother. random is not random , you will always get the same number, it is  math, you only can decrease the probability.

Comment: If I understand, you want the *user* to enter the primary key? You'd have to check it doesn't repeat, obviously.

Comment: When you say 'actor', do you mean 'user'?

Comment: Yes, I mean the user.

Comment: @nbk I don't think the questioner means 'random', I think they mean 'arbitrary'.

Comment: @PraiseDaMemes The answer is yes. Which is the same in all SQL databases. The notion of a primary key is not the same as the notion of an (auto-incrementing) identity. If you Google MySQL primary key and MySQL identity you'll find pages documenting the two different (if related, because an identity is often used as a PK) things.

Comment: i am not sure what exactly is he is asking, he can of course allow his users to select a unique identification and use that as primary key, which is possible, but like uuids theproblem is that query get slower as when you use auto_increment, besides you have to have enough space, to get unique user ids, and when you refere to it you need the same space. I an final point, you don't need an auto_increment but it is faszer and cost less space.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is trying to hide the system's total number of users from his audience. If that's the case I would suggest leave the primary key alone and use a 'slug' in your URI's etc that's made up of your random int, instead of exposing the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You actually have to specify `AUTO INCREMENT` or data type `SERIAL` for it to automatically increment values. If your `PRIMARY KEY` that will be referenced by this `FOREIGN KEY` is data type `SERIAL` then you will need to make the `FOREIGN KEY`'s data type `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. `SERIAL` is effectively an alias for setting the column to `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`. Setting the the `FOREIGN KEY` to `BIGINT UNSIGNED` would give it the same integer range as a serial.

Remember, a `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique. So if this table is meant to have multiple records that will reference a single record in the other table, you may be better off making a `PRIMARY KEY` that is type `SERIAL` and then have another column that is your `FOREIGN KEY` that is type `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. This would allow you to have multiple records with the same value for the `FOREIGN KEY` column but you will still have a valid `PRIMARY KEY`